# Prevent Mobile Browser Zooming of One HTML Element

Tags: html, css, mobile, resize

I'm wondering if anyone knows a way that you can prevent browser zooming of specific page elements.

This is for the mobile version of a site I'm developing. I have a fixed menu bar that runs full width of the site and remains at the top of the page at all times to provide navigation. I've optimised the button/text sizes to work for touch screens and don't really want it to be affected if a user zooms the page content text.

The only thing I've come across is the following CSS, but this doesn't seem to work when I've tried it:
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;

I'm do not wish to disable resizing of the whole page via the Viewport meta tag, I just want to target the menu bar html elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The zoom mechanism varies across browsers and is not standardized, nor is it scriptable. Any solution would be pretty convoluted in order to work across browsers. There is no easy way to do this.

Comment: I thought this may be the case, shame - I don't suppose I'm the only one to have had this problem. Thanks for taking the time to reply though.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a modal dialog based on a similar question, you can find it [here](https://github.com/salsita/jquery-ui-scalebreaker).

In essence, the logic is about getting the page scale ratio based on window.innerWidth and maximum page width, applying it as a CSS transform to the element and then repositioning it on screen. If there is interest, I will rewrite it into a library that just takes a position: fixed element as an input and does all this magic to it when the user zooms the page.